# Android colorize all texts between tags

Tags: android

You suppose i have this string which formatted with some tags:

```
String content = "11111<mft:A>22222</mft:A>111111<mft:R>33333<mft:A>22222</mft:A>333333<mft:S>444444</mft:S></mft:R><mft:A>2222222</mft:A>";
```

i want to colorize this string with extracting tags like with this screen shot:

[image: Android colorize all texts between tags]

unfortunately my wrote code doesnt correct and couldn't colorize correctly between tags:

my result code:

[image]

this below is my code which dont correct to colorize texts between tags

```
private List<AyehaTagsInformation>   ayeHaPositions     = new ArrayList<>();
private List<AsharTagsInformation>   sherHaPositions    = new ArrayList<>();
private List<RevayatTagsInformation> revayatHaPositions = new ArrayList<>();

private void extractTags(String str) {
    Pattern mftA_REGEX = Pattern.compile("<mft:A>(.+?)</mft:A>");
    Pattern mftR_REGEX = Pattern.compile("<mft:R>(.+?)</mft:R>");
    Pattern mftS_REGEX = Pattern.compile("<mft:S>(.+?)</mft:S>");

    Matcher matcher = mftA_REGEX.matcher(str);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        ayeHaPositions.add(new AyehaTagsInformation(matcher.start(1), matcher.end(1)));
    }

    matcher = mftR_REGEX.matcher(str);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        revayatHaPositions.add(new RevayatTagsInformation(matcher.start(1), matcher.end(1)));
    }

    matcher = mftS_REGEX.matcher(str);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        sherHaPositions.add(new AsharTagsInformation(matcher.start(1), matcher.end(1)));
    }
}


String content = "11111<mft:A>22222</mft:A>111111<mft:R>33333<mft:A>22222</mft:A>333333<mft:S>444444</mft:S></mft:R><mft:A>2222222</mft:A>";
    extractTags(content);

    Spannable wordToSpan = new SpannableStringBuilder(content);

    if (revayatHaPositions.size() > 0) {
        for (int p = 0; p < revayatHaPositions.size(); p++) {
            try {
                wordToSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), revayatHaPositions.get(p).getStart(), revayatHaPositions.get(p).getEnd(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("Error colorize: ", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    if (ayeHaPositions.size() > 0) {
        for (int p = 0; p < ayeHaPositions.size(); p++) {
            try {
                wordToSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), ayeHaPositions.get(p).getStart(), ayeHaPositions.get(p).getEnd(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("Error colorize: ", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    if (sherHaPositions.size() > 0) {
        for (int p = 0; p < sherHaPositions.size(); p++) {
            try {
                wordToSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), sherHaPositions.get(p).getStart(), sherHaPositions.get(p).getEnd(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("Error colorize: ", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

message.setText(wordToSpan);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String s1= "11111<mft:A>";
String s2= "<font color='#ff0000'>22222</font>";
String s3= "</mft:A><font color='#0000ff'>111111</font><mft:R>";
t.setText(Html.fromHtml(s1+ s2+s3));
```

Use Regex on same format for generalize answer

Comment: android doesn't support nested tags `<font>` html tag

Comment: Sir, i had verified on Android 6.0 please verify

Comment: please try this code: `String s3= "</mft:A><font color='#0000ff'>111111<font color='#3465A4'>2222</font>11111</font><mft:R>";`

Comment: you haven't close first font tag `String s3= "</mft:A><font color='#0000ff'>111111</font><font color='#3465A4'>2222</font></mft:A><font color='#0000ff'>11111</font><mft:R>";` Try this

Comment: please try this : `String s3= "</mft:A><font color='#0000ff'>111111</font><font color='#3465A4'>2222222222<font color='red'>111111</font>22222222222222</font></mft:A><font color='#0000ff'>11111</font><mft:R>";` couldn't support multiple nested tag

Comment: please try this : `String s3= "</mft:A><font color='#0000ff'>111111</font><font color='#3465A4'>2222222222</font><font color='red'>111111</font><font color='#0000ff'>22222222222222</font></mft:A><font color='#0000ff'>11111</font><mft:R>";`  Tag : 2 is not closed and 4 is not open

Comment: Thanks sir, i know what was problem now